# Is there a terser way to call a type conversion function on all elements within a nested array?

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

Imagine some function, convertType, which simply takes a number and converts it to a string representation of one's choosing, like so:

```
convertType(someNum : number) : string {
    return "Number is: " + someNum;
}
```

Then let there be some array:

```
myNestedArrayNum = new Array<Array<Array<number>>>();
```

What is the quickest way to iterated through this nested array, and, utilizing this conversion function, convert `myNestedArrayNum` to an `Array<Array<Array<string>>>` ?

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
convertNestedArray(numArray : Array<Array<Array<number>>>) : Array<Array<Array<string>>> {

    let strArray = new Array<Array<Array<string>>>();

    for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {

        let temp1 = new Array<Array<string>>();

        for (let j = 0; j < numArray[i].length; j++) {

            let temp2 = new Array<string>();

            for (let k = 0; k < numArray[i][j].length; k++) {

                temp2.push(convertType(numArray[i][j][k]);
            }
            temp1.push(temp2);
        }
        strArray.push(temp1);
    }
    return strArray;
}
```

However, there **must** be a terser way of doing this, right? We are allowed to assume we know the depth of the nested array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
// as many overloads as you need
function convertNestedArray<T, U>(f: (t: T) => U, v: Array<Array<Array<T>>>): Array<Array<Array<U>>>;
function convertNestedArray<T, U>(f: (t: T) => U, v: Array<Array<T>>): Array<Array<U>>;
function convertNestedArray<T, U>(f: (t: T) => U, v: Array<T>): Array<U>;
function convertNestedArray<T, U>(f: (t: T) => U, v: T): U;
function convertNestedArray<T, U>(f: (t: T) => U, v: T | Array<T>): U | Array<U> {
  if (Array.isArray(v)) return v.map(e => convertNestedArray(f, e));
  return f(v);
}

function convertType(someNum: number): string {
  return "Number is: " + someNum;
}

const s: string[][][] = convertNestedArray(convertType, [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]);

console.log(s);
```

This is using the array `map` function and recursion to convert.  You need to overload the function as many times as necessary to deal with the array depth you have.  (I don't think this can be done for arbitrary depth in TypeScript currently.)

Hope that helps.  Good luck!